# Какая динамическая структура быстрее читает данные

Tags: c++, динамические-структуры

На рассмотрение выбрал наиболее интересные варианты: vector, deque, list (двусвязный)

Comment: Что значит "читает"?

Comment: Читает данные из оперативной памяти

Comment: скорее всего Вам нужен vector. Если сомневаетесь, делайте бенчмарки.

Comment: Покажите код, потому что непонятно, что вы хотите. *В общем случае* вектор быстрее благодаря компактному размещению.

Answer (score 0):

Каждая динамическая структура имеет преимущество в какой-либо ситуации над другими структурами, иначе их просто бы не было, для перебора элементов подряд наиболее быстро работают структуры, основанные на массивах и списки, если нужен поиск по значению, то лидере дерево поиска